# How to find and install the GNU Smalltalk on CentOS or Fedora / RedHat?

Tags: centos, fedora, rhel, yum, rpm

On GNU Smalltalk's webpage, it says:

> Binary distributions
>
> We do not provide pre-compiled binaries for GNU
>   Smalltalk. However, most GNU/Linux distributions (Ubuntu, Debian,
>   Fedora) include packages for GNU Smalltalk.

so is it true that we can use, say, on CentOS (since it is in the same camp of Fedora):

```
yum search smalltalk
yum search all smalltalk
```

to search for it?  I can't find any result though, and if I do find anything, is the way to install it by `yum install _______`?

So how can I install the GNU Smalltalk package?

Answer (score 2):

The command `yum install gnu-smalltalk` works for me on Fedora 20.  The smalltalk package for my system is found in the fedora/20/x86_64 repository.  The command `yum repolist` should tell you which repositories are enabled on your system.  On my system there is a text file /etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo which contains the enabled=1 flag, in case yours has gotten disabled somehow.

Comment: maybe I give Fedora a try... on CentOS, it didn't work, and I wonder too, if on Fedora, if it works, then shouldn't `yum search` be able to find it too? (as a general search for both Fedora and CentOS)

Comment: also if I have the 7GB .iso image of CentOS Everything installation DVD, would the smalltalk package be in there?  I did a `find . -iname "*smalltalk*"` in that DVD and there was nothing found

Comment: @太極者無極而生  I do not know CentOS.  Maybe you can find smalltalk in an EPEL repo for CentOS.  An EPEL repo is a repository for extra packages.  Only install an EPEL repo from a trusted source.

Answer (score 1):

Not every package that exists in Fedora exists in CentOS. In fact, Fedora is much, much larger. We have a project called "EPEL" which is made up of Fedora packages built for Red Hat Enterprise Linux and CentOS. (And, occasionally, packages which aren't in the Fedora collection.) CentOS also has their own "Extras", some of which aren't even in Fedora — but that's mostly a smaller list.

In *this* case, `gnu-smalltalk` *is* part of the EPEL 7 repository, and also EPEL 5, but *isn't* in EPEL 6. (I'm not sure why that is exactly, but perhaps there was a build or compatibility problem and no one with the time and interest in figuring it it.) You can see this by searching [Fedora Packages list](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/), in this case landing at https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/gnu-smalltalk.

So, if you're on CentOS 5 or 7, and EPEL is enabled ([see here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)), `yum search smalltalk` *will* return with packages available. If you're on 6, you'll have to track down whatever the reason the package is missing there.